# schtasks output is in different encoding whether it runs locally or in remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to check the schedule tasks on my servers, and I would like to use background-jobs and remote sessions to speed up the execution of the script. 
But when i run my command in the remote session, the output is in a different culture ( or encoding ?) than onto my workstation.
I tried to use New-PsSessionOption but the result is the same :

1. locally run schtasks to check a remote server, output is OK :

   ```
   PS>Get-Culture

   LCID             Name             DisplayName
   ----             ----             -----------
   1036             fr-FR            French (France)

   PS>schtasks -s servername /v /query /fo csv |ConvertFrom-Csv |select -first 1


   Nom de l'hôte                                             : servername
   Nom de la tâche                                           : \BITS_CCM_Incoming_{16
                                                               674A29-EDDD-43C3-9EF2-
                                                               2B2D64EFA6F5}
   Prochaine exécution                                       : 23/11/2012 22:38:00
   Statut                                                    : Prêt
   ```
2. Open a remote session an run schtasks locally :

   ```
   PS>$pso = New-PSSessionOption -Culture "fr-fr"
   PS>etsn servername -SessionOption $pso
   [servername]: PS C:\> get-culture

   LCID             Name             DisplayName
   ----             ----             -----------
   1036             fr-FR            Français (France)
   [servername]: PS C:\> schtasks /query /v /fo csv |ConvertFrom-Csv |select -First 1


   Nom de l'h"te                                             : servername
   Nom de la tƒche                                           :     \BITS_CCM_Incoming_{16674A29-EDDD-43C3-9EF2-2B2D64EFA6F5}
   Prochaine ex'cution                                       : 23/11/2012 22:38:00
   Statut                                                    : Pr^t
   ```

as you can see deespite the same culture is used the output seems to be of different encondings. How to deal with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I've found that I can use the COM object 'Schedule.Service' to retrieve tasks info wich is not language dependant :

```
icm -AsJob -JobName getTasks -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock{
    $Schedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
    $Schedule.connect($env:computername)
    $Tasks = $Schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)
    $Tasks | Select-Object  Name,Path,State,Enabled,LastRunTime,LastTaskResult
}

$resu=wait-job getTasks |receive-job
remove-Job getTasks

$resu|sort PSComputerName
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide an exact answer, but check $OutputEncoding and [Console]::OutputEncoding  both locally and in a remote session.

Configure the remote session to match the working/local session.

Comment: not better using this code :  
`$ce=[console]::OutputEncoding  
$oe=$OutputEncoding  
icm -Session $s -ScriptBlock  {  
    [console]::OutputEnconding=$using:ce;  
    $OuptutEncoding=$using:oe;  
    schtasks  
}`

Comment: i found that i'm able to change the [console]::OutputEncoding in a local session, but when i run same command in a remote session an exception is raised :  
`[localhost]: PS C:\> [console]::outputEncoding=[system.text.encoding]::ascii
Exception lors de la dfinition de .OutputEncoding/: .Descripteur non valide
/
Au caract
re Ligne:1 : 1
+ [console]::outputEncoding=[system.text.encoding]::ascii
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting`